# Restrict user from selecting old dates in asp.net calendar.

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am using asp.net calendar with ajax extension in my project.

I want to restrict users from selecting current and old dates in the calendar when they are selecting Next appointment using the calendar.

Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook up to the DayRender event

```
protected void SomeCalendar_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.Date < DateTime.Now)
    {
        e.Cell.Text = e.Day.Date.Day.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Day.Date < DateTime.Now) 
        {
            e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
            e.Cell.Enabled=false;
        }

    }
```